# how to display error messages in laravel blade based on input request rule

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation

In my laravel 5.4 application I have a basic input form with fields `password` and `password_confirmation`. The form is validated using laravel form request validation.

Rules used for the password field validation are `required` and `confirmed`.

The validation error messages are displayed using the code: `{{$errors->first('password')}}` If this validation fails
it returns the first error where i want to display error based on the rule.

ie, I want to display `password.required` validation error message in one place and `password.confirmed` validation error message in another place.
I have tried something like this to get messages baased on rule `{{$errors->first('password')['confirmed']}}` and it returns the error

> Illegal string offset 'confirmed'.

How can i get error message based on the validation rule?

Answer (score 1):

If you review how the Error Bag is build I don't think you can easly do what you want to do.

```
ViewErrorBag {#357 ▼
  #bags: array:1 [▼
    "default" => MessageBag {#358 ▼
      #messages: array:3 [▼
        "name" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The field Name is required."
        ]
        "username" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The field Username is required."
        ]
        "password" => array:1 [▼
          0 => "The field Password is required."
        ]
      ]
      #format: ":message"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is just an example Error Bag from my application.

Comment: I have seen the same structure on my application. I needed to know is there any way to index the array with customized variables or rule name. eg: From your example the array **name** is indexed using number, what i need is index the array with the rule name. ie, 
` "name" => array:1 [▼
          'required' => "The field Name is required."
        ]`

Comment: Well I can't think of any way you are able to do that. Cause you have no control over the request validation functions. Maybe you have more luck if you do your own validation inside the controller?